# c# How to store RSA key-pair on iOS keychain [Xamarin]?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, keychain, touch-id

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms app, and in iOS I want to create a RSA key-pair and be able to store the key-pair in the iOS KeyChain and retrieve the publicKey from iOS KeyChain anytime i want to. However i'm facing some problems due to the lack of documentation available on the internet about this issue.
So i created my RSA key pair this way, since i have to send the public key in DER format to a server (using BouncyCastle).
`

```
        RsaKeyPairGenerator generator = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();

        generator.Init(new KeyGenerationParameters(new SecureRandom(), 2048));

        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = generator.GenerateKeyPair();

        RsaKeyParameters keyParam = (RsaKeyParameters)keyPair.Public;

        var info = SubjectPublicKeyInfoFactory.CreateSubjectPublicKeyInfo(keyParam);

        byte[] RsaBytes = info.GetEncoded();
```

`

and then i need to store the keys on KeyChain but i can't find anything that helps me so i tried this way (byte[] value = RsaBytes):

```
`        private void StoreKeysInKeychain(string key, byte[] value)
        {
        SecRecord record = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
                    {
                        ValueData = NSData.FromArray(value),
                        Generic = NSData.FromString(key)
                    };
        record.AccessControl = new SecAccessControl(SecAccessible.WhenUnlocked, SecAccessControlCreateFlags.TouchIDAny);
        SecStatusCode  err = SecKeyChain.Add(record);
    }`
```

First, i don't know if this is the best way to store anything is iOS KeyChain.
Second, when i get the 'ValueData' from KeyChain, i can't convert it back to a byte[] so i can't get my publicKey again anymore.
I get the key using the following method

```
         NSData GetRecordsFromKeychain(string key)
                {
                    SecStatusCode res;
                    var rec = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
                    {
                        Generic = NSData.FromString(key)
                    };

                    SecRecord match = SecKeyChain.QueryAsRecord(rec, out res);
                    if (match != null)
                    {
                        // nsdata object :  match.ValueData;
                        return match.ValueData;
                    }
                    return null;
                }
```

and i try to convert it back to a byte[] that represents my public key using the following methods:

```
    byte[] marshalBytes = new byte[nsdata.Length];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(nsdata.Bytes, marshalBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(nsdata.Length));
    byte[] storedBytes = ToByte(nsdata);
    byte[] convertedBytes = nsdata.ToArray();
```

No one of them is the same as RsaBytes:

```
    bool result1 = RsaBytes.SequenceEqual(storedBytes);         // FALSE
    bool result2 = RsaBytes.SequenceEqual(convertedBytes);  // FALSE
    bool result3 = storedBytes.SequenceEqual(convertedBytes); // TRUE
    bool result4 = marshalBytes.SequenceEqual(RsaBytes);    // FALSE
    bool result5 = marshalBytes.SequenceEqual(storedBytes);     // TRUE
```

So, summing up all the problems

1 - I don't know the best way to create an RSA key pair in iOS and get publicKey DER-encoded (so I used BouncyCastle)

2 - Don't know how to store it properly on KeyChain

3 - I can access the information i stored, however it's useless since I can't convert it back to a publicKey

4 - When trying to access the information the user should be prompt to use TouchID, always.

I can't find samples of this in the internet... I would really appreciate some help.
Many thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I am still struggeling with getting SecAccessControl to work the way i want it too, so i can only help you with 1-3.</s>

In my iOS apps i store a key pair using the *SecKey.CreateRandomKey* function.
To use this function you have to create an NSDictionary that holds the attributes used for the key generation.

```
private NSDictionary BuildKeyPairAttributes(int keySize)
    {
        IList<object> keyBuilder = new List<object>();
        IList<object> valueBuilder = new List<object>();

        keyBuilder.Add(IOSConstants.Preloaded.constKSecAttrIsPermanent);
        keyBuilder.Add(IOSConstants.Preloaded.constKSecAttrApplicationTag);
        keyBuilder.Add(IOSConstants.Preloaded.constKSecAttrAccessible);

        valueBuilder.Add(NSNumber.FromBoolean(true));
        valueBuilder.Add(KeyAlias);
        valueBuilder.Add(IOSConstants.Preloaded.constKSecAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly);

        NSDictionary privateKeyAttr = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(valueBuilder.ToArray(), keyBuilder.ToArray());

        keyBuilder.Clear();
        valueBuilder.Clear();

        keyBuilder.Add(IOSConstants.Preloaded.constKSecAttrKeyType);
        keyBuilder.Add(IOSConstants.Preloaded.constKSecAttrKeySize);
        keyBuilder.Add(IOSConstants.Preloaded.constKSecPrivateKeyAttrs);

        valueBuilder.Add(IOSConstants.Preloaded.constKSecAttrKeyTypeRSA);
        valueBuilder.Add(keySize);
        valueBuilder.Add(privateKeyAttr);

        return NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(valueBuilder.ToArray(), keyBuilder.ToArray());
    }

public bool CreateNewRSAKey(int keySize)
    {
        if (!Delete())
        {
            return false;
        }

        var keyGenerationAttributes = BuildKeyPairAttributes(keySize);
        var privateKey = SecKey.CreateRandomKey(keyGenerationAttributes, out NSError errCode);

        if (privateKey == null || errCode != null)
        {
            //Handle error
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

You find the possible keys and values for the attributes in Apples Documentation.
To get the values of the string constants you can use:

```
var handle = Dlfcn.dlopen(Constants.SecurityLibrary, 0);
constKSecAttrApplicationTag = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant(handle, "kSecAttrApplicationTag"); //replace with whatever constant you need
Dlfcn.dlclose(handle);
```

Here is the IOSConstants class with the used attributes:

```
class IOSConstants
{
    private static IOSConstants _singleton;

    public static IOSConstants Preloaded
    {
        get
        {
            if(_singleton == null)
            {
                _singleton = new IOSConstants();
            }
            return _singleton;
        }
    }

    public readonly NSString constKSecAttrKeyType;
    public readonly NSString constKSecAttrKeySize;
    public readonly NSString constKSecAttrKeyTypeRSA;
    public readonly NSString constKSecAttrIsPermanent;
    public readonly NSString constKSecAttrApplicationTag;
    public readonly NSString constKSecPrivateKeyAttrs;
    public readonly NSString constKSecClass;
    public readonly NSString constKSecClassKey;
    public readonly NSString constKSecPaddingPKCS1;
    public readonly NSString constKSecAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly;
    public readonly NSString constKSecAttrAccessible;

    public IOSConstants()
    {
        var handle = Dlfcn.dlopen(Constants.SecurityLibrary, 0);

        try
        {
            constKSecAttrApplicationTag = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant(handle, "kSecAttrApplicationTag");
            constKSecAttrKeyType = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant(handle, "kSecAttrKeyType");
            constKSecAttrKeyTypeRSA = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant(handle, "kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA");
            constKSecAttrKeySize = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant(handle, "kSecAttrKeySizeInBits");
            constKSecAttrIsPermanent = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant(handle, "kSecAttrIsPermanent");
            constKSecPrivateKeyAttrs = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant(handle, "kSecPrivateKeyAttrs");
            constKSecClass = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant(handle, "kSecClass");
            constKSecClassKey = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant(handle, "kSecClassKey");
            constKSecPaddingPKCS1 = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant(handle, "kSecPaddingPKCS1");
            constKSecAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant(handle, "kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly");
            constKSecAttrAccessible = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant(handle, "kSecAttrAccessible");
        }
        finally
        {
            Dlfcn.dlclose(handle);
        }
    }
}
```

When you create the key pair with this methods, you can get the public key with *SecKey.GetPublicKey().GetExternalRepresentation()*

```
 private SecKey GetKeyFromKeyChain()
    {
        var foundKey = SecKeyChain.QueryAsConcreteType(
            new SecRecord(SecKind.Key)
            {
                ApplicationTag = KeyAlias
            }, out SecStatusCode errCode);

        if (foundKey == null || errCode != SecStatusCode.Success)
        {
            //Handle error
            return null;
        }
        return foundKey as SecKey;
    }

 public byte[] GetPublicKey()
    {
        NSError errCode = null;

        var foundKey = GetKeyFromKeyChain();
        var publicKey = foundKey?.GetPublicKey();
        var publicKeyExternalFormat = publicKey?.GetExternalRepresentation(out errCode);

        if (publicKeyExternalFormat == null || errCode != null)
        {
            //Handle error
            return null;
        }
        return publicKeyExternalFormat.ToArray();
    }
```

On my iPhone 5s the returned public key is a simple asn1 sequence, containing the modulus and the exponent, to get it work with bouncy castle i convert this to the pkcs#8 public key format.

```
 var pkcs8PublicKey = new DerSequence(
     new DerSequence(
         new DerObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.1.1"),
         DerNull.Instance),
     new DerBitString(publicKeyFromKeyChain)
 ).GetDerEncoded();
```

**EDIT**

Using this attributes, iOS asks me for touch id every time i want to access the key

```
//in BuildKeyPairAttributes
keyBuilder.Add(IOSConstants.Preloaded.constKSecAttrIsPermanent);
keyBuilder.Add(IOSConstants.Preloaded.constKSecAttrApplicationTag);  
//constKSecAttrAccessControl = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant(handle, "kSecAttrAccessControl");
keyBuilder.Add(IOSConstants.Preloaded.constKSecAttrAccessControl);

valueBuilder.Add(NSNumber.FromBoolean(true));
valueBuilder.Add(KeyAlias);
valueBuilder.Add(new SecAccessControl(SecAccessible.WhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly, SecAccessControlCreateFlags.UserPresence));

NSDictionary privateKeyAttr = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(valueBuilder.ToArray(), keyBuilder.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) However how to import IOSConstants? =/

Comment: IOSConstants is one of my classes, it just load all the constants using the piece of code i added some minutes ago.

Comment: o.0 Wow nice... Many thanks! Could you please show the IOSContants class? I'm curious, now. Seems like your code is pretty clean, would like to see how you did it on IOSConstants :) Is "IOSConstants.Preloaded.const****" a method? You created a method to each constant?

Comment: I edited my answer and added the IOSConstants class. (I know its not best practices to do that much work in the constructor :-) )

Comment: Many thanks! Always learning :) Really thanks. Will try to implement your solution :) I'll give feedback as soon as i do it

Comment: Two questions: :D
1 - What do you do in Delete() method? You delete if an entry already exists?
2 - When converting the key, DerObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.1.1") the input string means what? Where can i get it?

Comment: 1: Yes it ensures that there is no key with this alias in the key chain before you add a new one

Comment: 2: "1.2.840.113549.1.1.1" means that the key in the asn1 structure is a RSA key

Comment: Thanks! I don't know if what i say is stupid but how can i convert to PKCS#1 instead of PCKS#8? I'm using PCKS#1

Comment: RFC3447 defines the PKCS#1 ASN.1 structure for a rsa public key as sequence of the modulus followed by the exponent. This should be the same format as in the return value of GetExternalRepresentation().
Just to clarify, here PKCS#1 means the structure of the public key, it has nothing to do with PKCS#1 padding, you can generate the key in bouncy castle using the PKCS#8 structure and encrpyt with the PKCS#1 padding.

Comment: I updated my answer, iOS should ask you for touch id every time you try to access the key when you replace the privateKeyAttributes with the new one.

Comment: Many thanks mate! Just edited my code, however it doesn't ask me for touch id =/ Maybe it's because of the simulator, i don't know. I sign data and it doesn't ask for anything... I still have some questions about this, don't know if you have patience to answer the few questions i have =/ I'm asking you things because i can't find answers online and following apple documentations not always i can't figure out the solution, not because "i want you to do my job", no really that =/ If possible could we speak on skype? If possible i'm kloudja or rkd_spkt@hotmail.com

Comment: I can totally understand you, i was in your situation some months ago, so don't worry ;-)
I will contact you on skype.

Comment: Thanks you very much =) Just need to prompt the fingerprint screen authentication whenever i want to sign the data and to correctly receive the signed data and the public key ( both byte[] ) on the server side to verify the signature. I think it's easy. Oh and ofc i'm thinking of storing the key in secure enclave

Comment: Hi Simon. Have a last question, sorry to bother. Already posted it on skype.
Thanks in advance pal, everything is working like a charm thanks to you!